# Not Creating empty directories in war file

Tags: java, war

I need to create some empty directories in my web application for future use. In my IDE, I created them, but when I ran my app, this folder isn't creates and doesn't exist in the app war file.

How can I create these empty folders in the war file an run time?

I know that adding a file (for example .empty file), will solve my problem, But it isn't a good solution.

Comment: Why do you want them? If you deploy your app as a war file you can't write to them anyway.

Comment: yes, I need them. This application have been deployed for other application to upload their files there. In fact user files, will be upload in these directories

Comment: As I said, if it's deployed as a war, you can't write to app-relative directories. IMO it's a *big* mistake to do so anyway, since a redeploy may delete those directories anyway. Write uploaded files to a directory outside of the web app.

Comment: My application is an empty app and is just responsible for showing this uploaded files, so just important thing in this app is it's directories and uploaded files.

Comment: My statement still stands; IMO you're doing it wrong. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume you can ever write to the filesystem in the location where your .war is unpacked.  There's no guarantee that the .war will even be unpacked, or if it is, where it will be unpacked.

You're better off with an external directory configured via a servlet context parameter, and using that for your storage.

Comment: after unzipping this war file in my webapps folder in my web container(tomcat). I explained my problem above.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using java servlets (I'm just assuming since it's a java application running in a tomcat as I read) you can implement the ServletContextListener interface to run you custom code on context event, for example creating folders

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        
       // check existence or create your folders
       // this is the code that will be run on context init

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

       // here you can run custom code when the context is destroyed

    }
}
```

Of course you need to add all the required descriptors in your web.xml file, most IDEs will do it for you, you can have your own custom parameters or a path to load a properties file, but anyways here is a snippet:

```
<listener>
    <description>ServletContextListener</description>
    <listener-class>org.your.package.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>your:param-name</param-name>
    <param-value>value</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>your:config-file</param-name>
    <param-value>path/to/config.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

hope, I'm not too late. I used this strategy before with the QuartzScheduler to setup backup/alerts job groups running in the background.

Comment: With this strategy, it is still not guaranteed that the WAR location is writable.

Comment: if the war location isn't writable then tomcat won't be able to extract the code in the first place, it cannot take place before the extraction. 
The application wouldn't exists and you can't preemptively create subfolders of the contents in the war file or the whole extraction will automatially fail.
Assuming the user running the tomcat process has write access to his subfolders, you can actually set custom permissions programmatically when you create the folders when the context is initialized

Comment: the WAR might not even BE extracted, because not all servlet containers do that.